# iPhone iOS jQuery function $('content').height(); bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

I've got a short script for solving absolute position height.

```
document.body.onresize = function () {
    contentHeightFix(currentConDiv);
}
contentHeightFix(currentConDiv);

function contentHeightFix(id) {
    currentConDiv = id;
    $('.heightFix').height($(id).height());
}
```

So I have an absolute div and it has text in it, so the height of div is variable. I've placed a blank div under this div, called it .heightFix and let jQuery set height of this div based on height of that absolute div.

Everything works fine on Mac, PC, android browsers. All of them, including Safari on MacOS.

But when I run this script on the iOS, it's bugged - look at screenshot 2. Script works perfectly until I scroll the page downwards (even 1px scroll breaks it, but scrolling up to the top is fine). That's weird in my opinion, cause the script doesn't operate with scrolling what so ever...

I can also attach screenshots of that behaving.

**Proper behaving (before I scroll down):**

[image]

**Wrong behaving (after I scroll even 1px down):**

[image]